# Custom default struct as optional parameter

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, struct

I have a struct called WindowProperties. It has 3 properties, a static Default and a constructor with optional parameters.

```
public struct WindowProperties
{
    public string Title;
    public int Width;
    public int Height;

    public static WindowProperties Default => new WindowProperties("Fury Engine", 1280, 720);

    public WindowProperties(string title = "Fury Engine", int width = 1280, int height = 720)
    {
        Title = title;
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }
}
```

I have a method which takes in a `WindowsProperties` as a parameter

```
public WindowsWindow(WindowProperties props = WindowsProperties.Default)
{
    Init(props);
}
```

This gives me an error `"Default parameter 'props' must be a compile-time constant"`

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two constructors like

```
public WindowsWindow()
    :this(WindowsProperties.Default) 
{}

public WindowsWindow(WindowProperties props)
{
    Init(props);
}
```